# Is id in array of type. Typecheck

Tags: typescript

I want to check if id is at id list:

```
type Page = {
  id: string;
};

type Resource = {
  pages: Page[];
  activePage: string;
};

// ok
const okResource: Resource = {
  pages: [{ id: 'some-page-id' }],
  activePage: 'some-page-id'
};

// fail
const errorResource: Resource = {
  pages: [{ id: 'some-page-id' }],
  activePage: 'some-not-existing-at-pages-id'
};
```

Is it possible? How?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgc2gXigbwFBSgSwCYBcUAzsAE44B2CA3BgL50aiRQBKExA9gK5kDGKdFihhEnIvCQBtALp1scfsBwA3CFIhFSFanUYYMAeiNQuAawz8ulUmfMdufQUUe8BQzNjFJiRaWi4hFAA5NwAthAAtD7R%20CFQ9LIANCJKKuqaRGFckTHiUfEMTCZQAGZwOAA2VjZ2EGRkXGRuzlrsnO6CUKheouJ%20UAFB2RHRsYV4CUmpispqGuKjudGUXMBREAAeOKRUCFFwG7HEkyHFQA)

Comment: Can page ids be string literals union like: `type ActivePage = 'some-page-id' | 'some-other-valid-id' | 'yet-another-id'` and then define `type Resouce = { pages: Page[], activePage: ActivePage }`?

Comment: No, i don't know possible strings, before define certain resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific concrete type in TypeScript corresponding exactly to what you consider a valid `Resource`, where the `activePage` must be exactly equal to the `id` of one of the `pages`.  If you want to be able to represent this at all in TypeScript, you'll probably need to think of it as more of a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), and use a helper function instead of a type annotation to validate that any given candidate value conforms to the constraint:

```
interface ConstrainedPage<P extends string> {
  id: P
}

interface ConstrainedResource<P extends string, A extends P> {
  pages: ConstrainedPage<P>[],
  activePage: A
}

const asResource = <P extends string, A extends P>(
  resource: ConstrainedResource<P, A>
) => resource;
```

Here we are making generic types `ConstrainedResource` and `ConstrainedPage` that keep track of the list of `id` and `activePage` properties.  Now your examples become:

```
// ok
const okResource = asResource({
  pages: [{ id: 'some-page-id' }, { id: 'some-other-id' }],
  activePage: 'some-page-id'
});

// fail
const errorResource = asResource({
  pages: [{ id: 'some-page-id' }],
  activePage: 'some-not-existing-at-pages-id' // error!
  //~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '"some-not-existing-at-pages-id"' is not assignable to type '"some-page-id"'
});
```

and everything behaves as desired.

---

Note that you don't necessarily need to define `ConstrainedPage` or `ConstrainedResource`; I just used them to explain what was going on.  You could instead write the helper function directly as:

```
const asResource = <P extends string, A extends P>(resource: {
  pages: { id: P }[],
  activePage: A
}) => resource;
```

Also note that by making your resource types generic, you'll need to drag around these extra generic type parameters wherever you need to keep track of this constraint.  Imagine changing all mentions of `Resource` to `ConstrainedResource<P, A>` and adding `P` and `A` to whatever scope is necessary.  So I'd suggest only using this constraint for initial validation of developer-submitted resources, and then widen it to your concrete `Resource` type for use in internal code that assumes it's already been validated:

```
// external-facing function
function acceptResource<P extends string, A extends P>(resource: ConstrainedResource<P, A>) {
  processResource(resource); // works
}

// internal-only function
function processResource(resource: Resource) {
  // assume this has already been validated
  const activePage = resource.pages
    .find(v => v.id === resource.activePage)!; // use non-null assertion (!), assume validated

}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgc2gXigbwFBSgSwCYBcUAzsAE44B2CA3BgL50aiRQBKExA9gK5kDGKdFihhEnIvCQBtALp1scfsBwA3CFIhFSFanUYYMVYBDIAzJdADCXSjrhUIeTQB4YUCAA8TlPMRLkVAgAfMLY+JIMhsamFoJQNnbkDpROHNx8gm4e3hC+-jpBADRQAII5Pn6woZjYYkjERIn2js7ibsFyRSJKKuqaRKVRGPy2pFBwxOm8AkLZXpUFgdQl5Qt5VTDBABQiZJwzgk1jya3TmRBuq8EYAJRQyKH7GbNMGAD0AFQjJxNTBxcHlB5rl8gFdAhVhUNv4tttnoctGFROJGuhcIRYFB6F0eso1BpxIMGPdHlAERc6J93oYPu8oFwANY-JIMxnnWZAyYcwTbWoohpEaRoDFEADk3AAthAALT1WX4MXYkoiiJQCVcaUyrjAAAWphliuxsm6inx-SJ6qlsvlhrwYpJTHe9IsOAANizxqYyFwyDyhNyAbM+SJ5WjhaKrZqbeI7Ur6Ca8X1CUhxdaZZQdTKvDhSEEZXBgHLUXGoM6PGQfWQAIQiZ0AP0bTcbwJlMqgABVwNAxQAidOZos5vPUAtFsN23tK3NQQd-Yg4BCUOAAIzd0GAXCgLB7-ejxaQk4d9FuTvp6zIy7dMriQSgZh4lHxtgwD6fKlsE34gjAwH9IMWcFijKaEwThClZmOJIyBSNIgyyGBrnufkwB9QRiH+F5eQgwRTzLekAHdfUZYhhnLGJLzga9bDdEB70fZ9KFfBiP0oUQ0M4TDEXheCkX9ZC63pSZiB4aVt11GddUmCY3X2OA8DolcIDyKBVCo-BCycERRlZXoCU0IEcIgAA6MMRGwYyzCoPBtlUB5QlUYz8AeZBUCM4y9ItJBbmrGh8KgHhiGgTNKAzHg3TdedTFYqBtmrW4SmE0ToDUt0NJMPBDHoIA)